# Upgrading Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

Hello I am facing problem in upgrading the laravel 5.1 to 5.2. I have added

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
    },
```

in my project composer.json

[Error screenshot][1]

Error on console window.

> PHP Notice:  date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID '' is invalid in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php
>   on line 41 PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging::configureHandler()
>   in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/ConfigureLogging.php
>   on line 59

Comment: It seems to be a .log file problem, check if it really exists.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably do composer update (be sure you want to do this) then composer dump-autoload which i believe is triggered by default if you have not altered your composer.json file. you would also want to run php artisan cache:clear